# IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'design' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new to spring and was referring Spring in Action 5ed. I'm using Thymeleaf template engine.
Below I've listed 2 controllers and 2 views. Each view has a form, and form validation is done with hybernate validator on domain object.

However when validation fails in case of first contoller (Design controller), I get the following exception
`Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'design' available as request attribute`.
But when validation fails in second controller (Order Controller), I don't get any exception.

In both cases, I'm not `model.addAttribute` inside `if(errors.hasErrors())`

Design Controller

```
@GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                 new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP), .....
                );

        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for(Type type : types) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(), filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }
        
        model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
        return "design";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processDesign(@Valid Taco design, Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("Errors in design");
            return "design";
        }
        log.info("Processing design " + design);
        return "redirect:orders/current";
    }
```

design

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
                    <h3>Designate your wrap:</h3>
                    <div th:each="ingredient : ${wrap}">
                        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span> <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            <h3>Name you taco creation</h3>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/><br> 
            <button>Submit your taco</button>
</form>
```

Order Controller

```
@GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        return "orderForm";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("Error in {}", order);
            return "orderForm";
        }
        log.info("Order sumbitted " + order);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

orderForm

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${order}">
            <h3>Deliver to</h3>
    
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
            <br/>
    
            <input type="submit" value="Submit order"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you try replacing `@Valid Taco design` with `@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design`?

Comment: Thanks! 
Yes, that works. But I wanted to know why I did not get same exception in case of Order Controller.

Comment: I think it is due to the name of the class. `Order order` matches with your `${order}`, while `Taco design` does not match with `${design}`. You could try to rename the `Taco` class to `Design` to be sure. I personally always add the argument to `@ModelAttribute` to avoid that kind of "magic".